# Test is failing with "Method not found" error

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, mstest, biztalk

I have configured BizTalk UnitTest Project to run on every check into TFS, but test run is failing with the below error:

> Method not found:
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.ControllerProxy
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.Tmi.GetControllerProxy(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.TestRunConfiguration,
>   System.Object)'.

Error details:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe /nologo /usestderr /searchpathroot:"C:\Builds\29\BizTalk\<proj>\Binaries" /resultsfileroot:"C:\Builds\29\BizTalk\<proj>\TestResults" /testcontainer:"C:\Builds\29\BizTalk\<proj>\Sources\BizTalk\<solution>\C<proj>.UnitTest\bin\Release\<proj>.UnitTest.dll" /publish:"<TFS path>" /noprompt /publishbuild:"vstfs:///Build/Build/2592" /teamproject:"BizTalk" /platform:"Any CPU" /flavor:"Release" 
Loading C:\Builds\29\BizTalk\<proj>\Sources\BizTalk\<soln >\<proj>.UnitTest\bin\Release\<proj>.UnitTest.dll...
Starting execution...
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 12.0.21005.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
For switch syntax, type "MSTest /help"
**Method not found: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.ControllerProxy Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.Tmi.GetControllerProxy(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Common.TestRunConfiguration, System.Object)'.**
```

Comment: As with all mstest questions, have you tried using [vstest.console.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155800.aspx) instead?  MSTest.exe is left for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are multiple version of VS is installed side by side in Build Server, ensure right version of MSTest.exe is used by Build Server to execute the unit test.

I have achieved it by setting exact path of MStest.exe to 'ToolPath property' of 'Run MSTest activity' in BTDF Default Build Definition.